# How to refresh multiple divs containing PHP queries using ajax

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I have built a calendar appointment script and want to display the results for any given day on a google map and a table below without having to refresh the whole page.  Currently, using ajax, the map refreshes perfectly but the table doesn't.

When the date is clicked in the calendar it is written via javascript to a hidden form field, then when the update button (submit) is clicked, ajax in the head submits the form in the background to overwrite the $updatedate variable, refresh the map div and the table div.

Currently the variable gets updated in the session, a script runs to update an xml file and the calendar successfully refreshes showing this xml data.  However the table div does not refresh.  If I manually refresh the whole page the new results are shown successfully so it is picking up the updated variable but not refreshing via the ajax.

I realise this is probably due to ajax being client side and php server side so the php queries are not being ran but I have also tried to use file_get_contents (which works for the xml generating script) inside the div to run these queries without loading the whole page but this just shows nothing so I think I'm missing something fundamental and possibly very simple!

```
--------- ajax in head to run update script and reload divs --------

<!-- silently submit the updatedate form to update the session variable.
Then reload the map and table divs using this new variable -->
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script>
  $(function () {
    $('#update').on('submit', function (e) {
      // stop the page from reloading
      e.preventDefault();
      // but submit the form
      $.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        url: 'actions/updatedate.php',
        data: $('#update').serialize(),
        success: function () {
          $("#map-outer").load("../map.php");
          $("#tbl-outer").load("../table.php");
        }
      });
    });
  });
</script> 


--------- main page --------

<div>calendar content here</div>

<div>customer details form here</div>

<div class="clear" style="text-align: left;">
    <!-- set default then let script overwrite -->
    <?php $updatedate = date('Y-m-d'); ?>
    <!-- run form (via ajax in head) to update variable and write to session -->
    <form id="update" method="post">
        <input type="hidden" name="updatedate" id="updatedate" />
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="update map and table" />
    </form>
    <!-- update variable form session -->
    <?php $updatedate = $_SESSION['updatedate']; ?>
    <br />
</div>

<div id="map-outer" class="twocol1">
    <?php include "../map.php" ?>  <!-- this page runs a script to pull the db values and write them to xml, then displays google map code -->
    <br /><br />
</div>

<div id="tbl-outer" class="twocol2">
    <?php include "../table.php" ?> <!-- this page pulls the db values and display them in a table -->
</div>



--------- map.php page --------

<?php
// silently run the db to xml script before loading the map //
file_get_contents("admin/actions/dbtoxml.php");
?>

<div id="map"></div>
<script> .....  script to show google map with custom markers .....  </script>



--------- table.php page --------

<h2>Morning</h2>

<?php
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM wasps_appointments WHERE date = '$updatedate' AND time = 'Morning' AND block = 0 AND completed = 0 ORDER BY date ASC";
    $result = $connection->query($sql);
?>
<?php include 'admin/includes/view-table-today.php'; ?>

<br /><br />

<h2>Afternoon</h2>

<?php
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM wasps_appointments WHERE date = '$updatedate' AND time = 'Afternoon' AND block = 0 AND completed = 0 ORDER BY date ASC";
    $result = $connection->query($sql);
?>
<?php include 'admin/includes/view-table-today.php'; ?>
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Many thanks, Helen

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed this now.  The table.php page wasn't loading using the existing mysql db connection so I had to use a different one.

Can anyone tell me the difference between using
    $connection = new mysqli(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASS, DB_NAME);
and
    $connection = mysqli_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASS);
    $db_selected = mysqli_select_db($connection, DB_NAME);